# Detect a string after a character in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, parsing

I have a string and i want to detect the value next to the string .
for eg:

```
string s="the #awb 58981140743 is the number";
```

The value next to #awb needs to be detected.I want the result string to be (after #awb) .

```
string output=58981140743;
```

Comment: Okay, so have you read through the string documentation to see which methods might be applicable? (Hint: IndexOf and Substring...) Also, this isn't really specific to ASP.NET at all..

Comment: RegEx is what you are looking for :)

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Did you *try* to solve this by yourself?

Comment: I have tried both Substring and RgEx.

Comment: Exactly. `Regex.Match(s, @"#awb\s*(\d+)").Groups[1].Value` - add a check to see if a match is `.Success`

Comment: @bksumedha what specifically did you try? Share the code.

Comment: tried using a substring      string str12 = s;
                    string specialChar = "#awb ";
                    string newStr = str12.Substring(str12.LastIndexOf(specialChar));

Comment: @bksumedha Your code needs to be posted along with the question. Also, I don't see any regex there despite you claiming to have tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below regex to solve your problem.

```
string s = "the #awb 58981140743 is the number";

string result = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\d]", "");
```

If you wan't specific string after #awb then use below code

```
string s = "the #awb 58981140743 is the number";

Regex.Match(s, @"#awb\s*(\d+)").Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: This works.Exactly .So regular expression is what i Wanted to use.

Comment: one of the best way to manipulate strings is by regular expresions : http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

Comment: It certainly works for integer values.Whats ur opinion on values which includes the decimal values. Say that the value is 25.14.                                    Regex.Match(s, @"#awb\s*(\d+)").Groups[1].Value; .This code fetches only the value of 25 and neglects .14 value

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "the #awb 58981140743 is the number";

            if (s.IndexOf("#awb") >= 0)
            {
                var temp = s.Split(new string[] { "#awb" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
            }
```

this code snippet will give you the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s="the #awb 58981140743 is the number";
var splittedValue= s.Split(new string[] { "#awb" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
```

This is how simply you can split and show your value